# Nokogiri 1.6.1 won't install on Mavericks/Rails 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I'm a newbie to setup/config, but previously had older (1.8.7)/newer (2.0) versions of Ruby and Rails installed and running on my Mac (Mavericks), but am working on someone else's code that requires 1.9.3/3.2 and have spent the past three days trying to get it work to no avail.  I've been able to get Ruby 1.9.3p429 installed, but when I do `rails -v`, it says:

> Could not find nokogiri-1.6.1 in any of the sources Run `bundle
>   install` to install missing gems.

So I tried that and I got the following error in gem_make.out:

```
> /Users/sa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby extconf.rb
> /Users/sa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in
> `<top (required)>': It seems your ruby installation is missing psych
> (for YAML output). To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml
> and reinstall your ruby. Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into
> tmp//ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK Running 'configure' for libxml2
> 2.8.0... ERROR, review 'tmp//ports/libxml2/2.8.0/configure.log' to see what happened.
> *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
> the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
> options.
> 
> Provided configuration options:   --with-opt-dir  --with-opt-include
>   --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include    --with-opt-lib
>   --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
>   --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir
>   --ruby=/Users/sa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby
> /Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:265:in
> `block in execute': Failed to complete configure task (RuntimeError)
>   from
> /Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:257:in
> `chdir'   from
> /Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:257:in
> `execute'     from
> /Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:65:in
> `configure'   from
> /Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:108:in
> `cook'    from extconf.rb:101:in `block in <main>'    from
> extconf.rb:119:in `call'  from extconf.rb:119:in `block in <main>'
>   from extconf.rb:109:in `tap'    from extconf.rb:109:in `<main>'
> 
> extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Steps I've tried without success include:

- reading/trying everything on SO and Github
- uninstall/reinstalled brew and RVM
- installed XCode command line tools
- linked libxml2 and libxslt, etc.

Bashrc contains:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2
export CPP=/usr/local/bin/cpp-4.2
export CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++-4.2
#export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9
#export CPP=/usr/local/bin/cpp-4.9
#export CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++-4.9
```

I'm at a loss for what to do next.  Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're on the right track.  Nokogiri is slightly special because it relies on a specific version of libxml that it gets from whatever's in the system path.  Make sure you have XCode up to date and have the command line tools installed, and I recall being able to solve this (in the past) without having to export or force any special versions of compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues but was able to get it running successfully with this command

```
ruby -v ; gem i -i xxx nokogiri -v '1.6.2.1'
```